# Blogger post thumbnail not working in home

Tags: html, templates, blogger

[My blog](https://myneobuxportal.blogspot.com/)

Recently i am getting no thumbnail in some of my blogger post which is shown in the home menu. I am using custom template. But i don't think the template has issues. Because i tried with some other custom templates. But the thing is its showing thumbnail correctly in stock template like flipcard, sidebar. Also it is showing correctly in mobile view. Even if i delete and repost the same post this problem occurs.

But if i try some random name for my post like "asdasdsawfe" the thumbnail sometimes works. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind just figured it out. My template didn't support special character. So the character (') was the reason for it.